# Pseudo Mercator error?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin, web-mercator

I'm mapping on QGIS, I have a vector layer and his CRS is on EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, but also I wanted to put a satellite image, so when I do it, the image use WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. 
The problem is, this CRS shows me differents degrees. And If I set project CRS from the vector layer, that will cut the image. Thus, I want the map with the coordinates of the vector layer.
Can I do it? How?

Answer (score 1):

The openlayers plugin requires EPSG:3857 Pseudo Mercator, because that is the CRS the tiles from Google or Openstreetmap are delivered in. The CRS has units called metres, although they are real metres only at the aequator.

It is not a good idea to switch from that CRS to another, because then all tiles will be reprojected individually, leading to nasty spaces between the deformed rectangles.

Principally it would be possible to stitch the tiles together and reproject the whole picture in one, but that would take too much time while panning around.

The only thing you could do is create a vector grid in degrees with CRS:4326, and lay it over your canvas.

Comment: How can I label the vector grid with the coordinates?

Comment: Just name the grid lines after the degree. Natural Earth offers 10-degree-graticules for the whole world. Either take that or make a similar vector file.