# why are my buffers not lining up with their original points despite setting the layer crs as all the same crs when I reopen my project

Tags: qgis, point, buffer, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am having my entire project in pseduo mercator (google earth raster image) and when I create buffers for points and then open back up my project all the buffers are offset from their points.

Update: [pseudo-mercator-error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/pseudo-mercator-error)

So my buffers I got to line up with their original centers, but other points that I meant to place within proximity were offset. I think it has something to do with meters and relative buffer distance being the reason why the buffers were fixed, but not some of the points.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Some layer has wrong CRS settings.

To debug the problem, please list all layers and their CRS settings. Double check if the point layer was created in Webmercator. Double check the CRS info of the buffer layer and the CRS settings in the buffer layer's properties.

From the current description, it is not clear how the "other points" were created. Please clarify.

Comment: So I grouped them all and I noticed that setting the CRS of the group doesn't seem to work whereas it slightly adjusts if I set the layers individually.

Comment: @CarlCarlson Please clarify how you create the "other points"

Comment: sorry, so essentially I created some points and then created buffers and I created some other points that were essentially tangential to my buffers. When I created all of them I created them with the pseudo-mercator projection. the points that were supposed to be touching the border of my buffers are offset.

Comment: I guess if there is a way I can snap points together that are close to each other that would work for redoing my project.